# CSS: position:absolute cropping inside not-nearest overflow:hidden parent

Tags: html, css

We have carousel code like this:

```
<div style="width:280px; height:100px; border:1px solid red; overflow:hidden; ">
    <ul>
        <li style="position:relative; width:200px; height:50px; list-style-type:none; background:yellow;">
            <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:180px; height:150px; background:Pink; z-index: 99;">
                <br/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Last div, which is positioned absolute, is cropping. Is there any way to do it works normal by changing only ccs code?

Comment: "overflow: hidden" in main div is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to remove `overflow: hidden`, then is it ok for you to remove `position:relative` for inner `li` and this to some new outer div and add appropriate top and left values to the pink div as below.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="width:280px; height: 100px; border:1px solid red; overflow:hidden; ">
        <ul>
            <li style="/* removed position:relative; */ width:200px; height:50px; list-style-type:none; background:yellow;z-index: 3;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 52px; width:180px; height:150px; background:Pink; z-index: 99;">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thats the only way I could figure out!

Comment: But after removing it, pink DIV is not positioned on the LI.

Comment: I changed the top and left values as well.. did you change them also?

Comment: And also to keep it undisturbed, there's an extra outer div added!

Comment: If there is one LI inside, there is no problem with your code. but in carousel i have about 10-15 LI inside the UL, and pink DIV is in each LI. And each pink DIV must be positioned on his parent LI.

Answer (score 1):

you have given `overflow:hidden` to the main `div` which has `width:280px`

and so the last `div` with `position:absolute` is getting chopped off.

Comment: That's ok @skshoyeb this happens

Comment: main div is making auto by the carousel code. if I remove overflow:hidden in main div, jquery.carousel brokes.

Comment: you want that pink div to be out of the main div? like cutting out from border?? or just you want the full pink div inside the border?

Comment: I want that pink div to be out of the main div.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div style="width:280px; height:100px; border:1px solid red; /* removed overflow:hidden; */ ">
    <ul>
        <li style="position:relative; width:200px; height:50px; list-style-type:none; background:yellow;">
            <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:180px; height:150px; background:Pink; z-index: 99;">
                <br>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can'n remove it, because it's need to carousel script.

Comment: Then increase the height of the outer div.